# Horizontal draggable scrollbar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll

https://pub.dev/packages/draggable_scrollbar

I tried that draggable scrollbar and it works - but only in vertical direction.

I checked its code and found that the Maths they have used allows it to be dragged only in a vertical direction.

What is the way to have a horizontal draggable scrollbar?
Or
What is the way to have buttons on the ends of the list which (on press) would move the contents left and right?

Comment: Check this pull request https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter-draggable-scrollbar/pull/21 , but not merged.

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak Thank you very much for pointing out. Please put that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flutter has a scroll bar now and it detects the direction of scroll. Additionally you can also mention the position of scroll bar.

```dart
Expanded(
            child: Scrollbar(
              interactive: true,
               trackVisibility: true,
              thumbVisibility: true,
              child: ListView.builder(
               scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: 20,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(index.toString()),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

**EDIT**
I have created a demo and I am able to hold the bar and able to drag it..

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: Page1());
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Page1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Page1> createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Scrollbar(
              controller: _scrollController,
             interactive: true,
              trackVisibility: true,
              child: ListView.builder(
                controller: _scrollController,
                itemCount: 20,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                    width: 120, height: 100, child: Text(index.toString())),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: preview]

[image: flutter version]

Comment: It is draggable.. Scrollbars are interactive and can use the PrimaryScrollController if a controller is not set. Interactive Scrollbar thumbs can be dragged along the main axis of the ScrollView to change the ScrollPosition. Tapping along the track exclusive of the thumb will trigger a ScrollIncrementType.page based on the relative position to the thumb.

Comment: Did it work as expected?

Comment: Updated my answer with a working demo. Please let me know if it worked as expected.. also my version is 2.10.3 and it works good

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I am on Andriod. Scrollbar interactive is false by default. I added `interactive: true` and now I am able to drag it by my thumb. Please add this to your code and then I will accept it as an answer.